# c# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error , tried to match textbox and databse value

Tags: sql, database, compiler-errors

i have a little problem in my code, i tried to match my textbox value to database, bu i get an error message ...

here is my codes:

my main code;

```
 protected void btnAddNewTopic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtbAddNewTopic.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please write topic!");
        }
        else if (goodob.Businness_Layer.AddNewTopic.NewTopicCheckSystem(txtbAddNewTopic.Text) == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your added topic is already in site!");
        }
        else
        {
            goodob.Businness_Layer.CreateNewTopic.crnewtopic(txtbAddNewTopic.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Your topic has successfully created!");
        }



    }
```

and my check code ;

```
 public static goodob.Businness_Layer.AddNewTopic NewTopicCheckSystem(string topic)
    {
        goodob.Businness_Layer.AddNewTopic xyz = null;

        string query = @"SELECT [topic_name] 
                       FROM topic
                       WHERE topic_name = @topic";

        goodob.Class1 connection1 = new goodob.Class1();
        connection1.sqlcommand.CommandText = query;

        SqlParameter topicparam = new SqlParameter("@topic_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        topicparam.Value = topic;

        connection1.sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(topic);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = connection1.sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            connection1.close_connection();
            return null;
        }




        return xyz;
    }
```

i get an error in  connection1.sqlcommand.CommandText = query; please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You have done too much confusion in adding parameters,you should add your sqlparameter object i.e.topicparam insted of topic.

use @topic varibale on both places.

or alternativly you can try this short hand

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @topic",topic);

insted of

```
 SqlParameter topicparam = new SqlParameter("@topic_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    topicparam.Value = topic;

    connection1.sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(topic);
```

Comment: i do that but still get an error message :( i get an this error message is in connection1.sqlcommand.CommandText = query; program don't pass this statement...

Comment: No matter what i do , i get error message ... i wonder my fault is in this statement  else if (goodob.Businness_Layer.AddNewTopic.NewTopicCheckSystem(txtbAddNewTopic.Text) == null)